# can I change the date of travel to the UK after filling out the online form?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

After filling out my online form I had to change the date of my travel to UK, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a big deal. Plans change. I've changed my dates of travel after obtaining visas plenty of times. If you haven't submitted the form, you may cross out the dates and change them with a pen.